# Simple explanation of checking prime numbers

Tags: javascript

I would like someone to explain me, how this code work? Because I cannot understand exactly.
This code write in console all prime numbers between 2 and n.

```
let n = 10;

nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
   for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
   }
   console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Please explain which parts of the code you *do* understand. Are you having problems with the syntax? With the algorithm?

Comment: is this the actual code? what's `nextPrime`? I don't see it defined anywhere

Comment: @sagar1025 `nextPrime:` is a label for the outer loop

Comment: @sagar1025 that's a loop label, quite rarely used JavaScript feature.

Comment: How work two 'for' loops in this case?

Comment: I cannot understand how this for loops work, how check every number, how it is work

Comment: @JakubSadowski cześć :) Try to draw it step by step to understand how it works. It's very common to have nested loops.

Comment: @JakubSadowski It runs the inner loop for each iteration of the outer loop, is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prime number is a number that can be divided by 1 and itself and has no other dividers.

This code loops over `<2...n)` range to check if the number can be divided by it (`i % j == 0`). If it can be divided by that number, it means that `i` is *not* a prime number, so we `continue nextPrime`, which means ending current iteration and proceeding to the next one. If we never run `continue` for particular `j`, it means it's a prime number.

Since you asked about nested loops, I'll try to explain why they are like that here. For simplicity, let's assume we need all prime numbers up to 5 instead of 10. Your loop is as follows:

```
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
   for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
```

That means that we're gonna check the following pairs of `i` and `j`, in order:

```
i = 3, j = 2
i = 4, j = 2
i = 4, j = 3
i = 5, j = 2
i = 5, j = 3
i = 5, j = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the function of inner for loop is to check whether the current value of i is prime or not.
Now how inner loop will do this ? See the basic definition if a number is divisible by only 1 and itself then it is prime no. But here the value of "j" is starting from 2 and going upto less than that number. So if "i" is divisible from any other no. then condition (i%j==0) will become true and code written inside that block will be executed.
And the code written inside it is `continue nextPrime` which will redirect the execution of program again to where `nextPrime` keyword is written. So the `console.log(i)` statement will not execute for that value of i.
And if condition not becomes true (means when it is prime) then it execute the last line which will print that no.